# Eclipse maven plugin error

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, maven

I frequently receive this error:

```
Plug-in 'org.maven.ide.eclipse.refactoring' contributed an invalid 
Menu Extension (Path: 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.refactoring.menu' is 
invalid): org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor.RenameProjectAction
```

How possible fix or workaroung this error?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you didn't install JDT for your eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like [bug 352943](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352943) (and [MECLIPSEWTP-140](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MECLIPSEWTP-140)) which should be fixed in 3.7.1